# Ajax Filters are not updating on first load based on url parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, filter

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'team_filter_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'team_filter_ajax' );

function team_filter_ajax() {
    $category = isset( $_POST['category'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['category'] ) : 'all';
    $search_term = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['search_term'] );
    print_r($category);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'member',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    );

    // Create an empty tax_query array
    $tax_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    );

    if ( $category !== 'all' ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'members_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category,
        );
    }

    if ( $search_term ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'member', // Adjust this to your post type
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            's' => $search_term,
        );
    }

    // Add the tax_query to the main $args
    if ( ! empty( $tax_query ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $response = '';

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $response .= render_template( 'template-parts/parts/member-item.php' );
        }
    } else {
        // No members found
        $response = 'No members found.';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $response;
    die();
}
```

I need to make this filter work based on the parameters sent in url , for example: mydomain/pagename/?cat=category-name, but it is always "all" for category, that means that `$_POST['category']` is empty on my first page load. After I select from the dropdown this variable `$category` will change based on the name of the parameter. So the filter is always showing all team members on first page load. Except this everything works and filer is working as expected:

Here is my jquery code

```
var $ = require('jquery');

require('webpack-jquery-ui/selectmenu');


$(function() {
    initAjaxParameters();
    initCategorySelect();
    filterTeam();
    ajaxFilter();
});


$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null){
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
    }
};


let parameters = {};
let postsXhr = null;


function filterTeam() {

    // Initialize the selectmenu widget
    $('#category').selectmenu({
        change: function (event, ui) {
            var category = ui.item.element.data('category'); // Get the data-category attribute
            var searchTerm = $('#search-member').val(); // Get the search term
            

            let url = '';

            if (category) {
                url = url + '?cat=' + category;
            }
            ajaxFilter(category, searchTerm);
            window.history.pushState('next', document.title, url);
        }
    });
    

    // Add an event listener for the search input field
    $('#search-member').on('input', function () {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        var category = $('.filter-wrap > select').find('option:selected').attr('data-category');
        ajaxFilter(category, searchTerm);
    });
}
function initAjaxParameters() {
    parameters.action = 'team_filter_ajax';
    parameters.category = $.urlParam('cat'); // Set the initial category from URL

    // Set the selected option in the select menu

    $('#category').val(parameters.category);

    if (parameters.category) {
        $('#category .ui-menu-item').filter(function () {
            console.log('here');
            return $(this).data("category") == parameters.category;
        }).click(); // Use .click() to trigger the click event
    }
}



function initCategorySelect() {
    $('#category').selectmenu({
        change : function(){
            parameters.category = $(this).val();
            ajaxFilter();
         
        }
    });
}

function pushHistory() {
    let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

    if(parameters.category){
        url = url + '?cat=' + parameters.category;
    }

    window.history.pushState('next', document.title, url);
}


function ajaxFilter(category, searchTerm) {
    pushHistory();
    $('.ajax-loader').removeClass('opacity-0');
    if(postsXhr){
        postsXhr.abort();
    }

 
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_params.ajaxurl,
        data: { action: 'filter', category: category, search_term: searchTerm },
        type: 'post',
    
        success: function (result) {
            $('.team-section__wrap .inner').html(result);
            $('.ajax-loader').addClass('opacity-0');
        },
        error : function(){
            console.log('Something went wrong!');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in team_filter_ajax function, You need to modify your team_filter_ajax filter to check GET parameter as well. Like this

```
$category = isset($_POST['category']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['category']) : (isset($_GET['cat']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['cat']) : 'all');
```

and slightly you need to modify your js code for server-side response :

```
$(function() {
    initAjaxParameters();
    initCategorySelect();
    filterTeam();

    let initialCategory = $.urlParam('cat');
    if(initialCategory) {
        ajaxFilter(initialCategory, '');
    } else {
        ajaxFilter('all', '');
    }

});
```